# Replace lines from one text to another with string match

Tags: regex, string, text, match, line

I want to replace lines matching one string to another file (text) .
for example , i have a file :

```
some line
some line
Style: Default,some text1
Style: Second,some text2
Style: Top,some text3
```

and the second file :

```
some line
Style: Default,something else
Style: NewInThisFile,some text
```

I want to use "Style: (any)," as string and replace lines from second file to first file . so the input will be :

```
some line
some line
Style: Default,something else
Style: Second,some text2
Style: Top,some text3
```

And it would be great if it was for multi files, like file1 and file2 and file3 as the first file ,
and the StringFile as a sample for all of them ( second file )

I have so little information about scripting , and I just want to know If anyway is possible .

Comment: http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/regular_expressions.html does this help? Your question is very broad, is this specifically ONLY for Regex? In what environment are you using the Regex?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me. But if you are using shell scripting in Linux you can use the "grep" command to search for your string in any file and them can save its result to a string or buffer and write it to the desired file using "cat" command, learn the "grep" command it will make your task easy.

Comment: what makes you think the OP is intending to use Shell Scripting on Linux?

Comment: Im using windows , and i want to work on text files . i just dont know which program ( or language ) to use

Comment: that question is farrrrr to broad for SO, @Mohammad . It's best to do some Google searches, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question -- yes absolutely this is totally possible, I would suggest using something like https://www.regex101.com to play and tweak your Regex code to do what you want,

As for implementation, iF you are working on local files, then you would need a local programming IDE, something like C++, C# or Python are pretty reliable. Check out

http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/programming-languages-for-beginners,1-2648.html

and there are various other Google results for guiding you what programs to use to reach this end. The big difference is some languages (such as PHP) are aimed primarily for Online/network work, servers and hosts etc. etc. while others (the one's in the link above) are aimed at local environments on your computer.